Advice on duct run route for bathroom extractor?
I'm planning a bathroom refurb soon which will involve replacing and rerouting my ventilation system.
The L-Shaped wall will be knocked down and the wall on door-side will be rebuilt.
Bathroom will be roughly 20sqm^3 and the kitchen (below room) has a cooking extractor.
Questions:

Is an MEV or inline extractor fan best suited for the job? (Yellow box)
Is it suitable to run an in-wall flat duct (blue line) in the stud wall for the Kitchen below?
Is it possible to run an in-wall flat duct (red line) horizontally through the stud wall or the ceiling (~3.6m high)? (The Bathtub sink will be the other way round).  (Red box, bathroom extractor)

Happy to hear other professional alternatives or opinions, thank you!


What are the yellow and red boxes?

Oh sorry, the yellow box is the planned MEV/inline exhaust fan unit.
The red box is the bathroom extractor!

Will the inline fan be accessible from the tub/shower?  You're wanting to connect the bath vent to the kitchen vent?

Ideally something central, but let me know if that's not a good idea?

As long as each vent "source" has a backflow preventer, I don't see it as a huge problem.  You may have local regulations that must be satisfied though.  Sounds like you are outside the USA.

Understood thank you. Yes based I'm based in the UK
